# Upload pictures and make them show together with my post

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload, content-management-system

I need help with a function so that I can upload a picture from my custom CMS, then have it shown together with my post. Look at the picture below:
[I want a picture in this image placeholder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWWwJ.png)
I'm not so good at PHP or Mysql so please give me a easy answer.

I'll post my code over here at pastebin, easier for you to watch over there! http://pastebin.com/gBVe9sZV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to show a set of images with your post, you'll need to store those images in a table along with the post id that they are associated with.

Upon submitting your form you're probably handling the post data via [`$_POST`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php). Your images will come across under [`$_FILES`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php). Once you have performed an insert on your post table, you can call [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) to get the new primary key ID for that post.

The post id can be stored in your *images* table along with references to your various images. I'm assuming here that you aren't generating your own post id's, however if you are you'd use that instead.

See also [Handling File Uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php), on php.net.

Whenever you're querying your database to show the post to your readers, perform a JOIN on the images table based upon a common post id, and you'll have the paths to all related images.

See also [Understanding JOINs in MySQL and Other Relational Databases](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/#fbid=FBk496PQSUE), on sitepoint.com.